# Access to U S V with Eigen SVD

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, svd

I'm getting crazy with this: I've just used the SVD in this way:

```
Eigen::BDCSVD<Eigen::MatrixXcd> svd(A, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);

const Eigen::MatrixXcd U = svd.matrixU();
const Eigen::MatrixXcd V = svd.matrixV();
const Eigen::VectorXd S = svd.singularValues();
```

After I needed to read some values like here:

```
valsingn = S/S(0);
```

or here:

```
tmp_var =  U(i, j);
```

Now I'd like to remove the copies of `U V` and `S` to avoid wasting of memory (my matrixes are huge `262144x576`), but I don't know how to access `U` from `svd.matrixU()`.

just writing `svd.matrixU(i, j)` doesn't work...

So my question is, how can I access `U S V` without copying them?

Comment: Did you try `const Eigen::MatrixXcd &U = svd.matrixU()`? Or do you want to delete them out of your `svd` object?

Comment: @chtz, yes, it worked! thank you!